# Ошибка при работе с dll

Tags: c, dll, c#

Есть Dll написанная на С++
Структура:

```
typedef struct {
SSP_FULL_KEY Key;
unsigned long BaudRate;
unsigned long Timeout;
unsigned char PortNumber;
unsigned char SSPAddress;
unsigned char RetryLevel;
unsigned char EncryptionStatus;
unsigned char CommandDataLength;
unsigned char CommandData [255];
unsigned char ResponseStatus;
unsigned char ResponseDataLength;
unsigned char ResponseData [255];
unsigned char IgnoreError;
} SSP_COMMAND;

typedef struct {
unsigned __int64 FixedKey;
unsigned __int64 EncryptKey;
} SSP_FULL_KEY;
```

Пытаюсь написать на c# программу которая бы использовала данную dll. выползает ошибка:

> Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
>   вот код:

```
 public unsafe struct SSP_FULL_KEY
    {
        System.Int64 FixedKey;
        System.Int64 EncryptKey;
        public SSP_FULL_KEY(System.Int64 fix, System.Int64 encr)
        {
            FixedKey = fix;
            EncryptKey = encr;
        }

    }
    public unsafe struct SSP_COMMAND
    {
        //string PortNumber;
        SSP_FULL_KEY key;
        System.Int64 BaudRate; // baud rate of the packet
        System.Int64 Timeout; // how long in ms to wait for a reply from the slave
        string PortNumber; // the serial com port number of the host
        string SSPAddress; // the SSP address of the slave
        string RetryLevel; // how many retries to the slave for non-response
        string EncryptionStatus; // is this an encrypted command 0 - No, 1 - Yes
        string CommandDataLength; // Number of bytes in the command
        fixed char CommandData[255]; // Array containing the command bytes
        string ResponseStatus; // Response Status (PORT_STATUS enum)
        string ResponseDataLength; // how many bytes in the response
        fixed char ResponseData[255]; // an array of response data
        string IgnoreError; // flag to suppress error box (0 - display,1- suppress)

        public SSP_COMMAND(string comport)
        {
            BaudRate = 9600;
            Timeout = 500;
            PortNumber = comport;
            RetryLevel = "5";
            IgnoreError = "0";
            EncryptionStatus = "0";
            ResponseStatus = "0";
            ResponseDataLength = "0";
            SSPAddress = "0";
            CommandDataLength = "0";
            key = new SSP_FULL_KEY(0123456701234567, 0123456701234567);

        }
    }
    class Program
    {

        [DllImport("ITLSSPProc.dll")]

        private static extern int OpenSSPComPort(SSP_COMMAND cmd);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SSP_COMMAND cmd = new SSP_COMMAND("6");

            Console.WriteLine(OpenSSPComPort(cmd));
       }
Помогите плз, неделю бьюсь не могу победить. Заранее спасибо
```

Answer (score 1):

ref еще не забудьте)

```
[DllImport("ITLSSPProc.dll")]
private static extern int OpenSSPComPort(ref SSP_COMMAND cmd);
```

P.S.
Используйте лучше [это](http://code.google.com/p/sspcomm/):

Answer (score 0):

М-м-м. Я ни черта не понимаю в С#, но прошу обратить внимание на следующие вещи:

1. Размер переменных. Мне очевидно, что sizeof(unsigned long) = 4 byte = 32 bits, а это, ну, никак не коррелирует с Int64. А еще unsigned char = Int8 или Byte или как он там у Вас в C# называется, но явно не string.
2. aligment. Лучше задавать явно. Иначе что там компилятор наворотит - очень большой вопрос.

Comment: А почему 8 байт = 32 бита?

Comment: потому что опечатался